# Lie group homomorphism to $S^1$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-homomorphism, morphism

I wish to know the general strategy to deal with a compact Lie group $G$ and its Lie group homomorphism $G$ to $S^1$ as:
$$
\text{Hom}(G, S^1).
$$
Here $S^1=U(1)$.

For example, how could we determine:
$$
\text{Hom}(SO(n), S^1)=?
$$
$$
\text{Hom}(SU(n), S^1)=\mathbb{Z}_n?
$$
$$
\text{Hom}(Sp(n), S^1)=?
$$
$$
\text{Hom}(Spin(n), S^1)=?
$$
$$
\text{Hom}(F_4, S^1)=?
$$
$$
\text{Hom}(G_2, S^1)=?
$$
$$
\text{Hom}(E_6, S^1)=?, \text{Hom}(E_7, S^1)=?, \quad \text{Hom}(E_8, S^1)=?
$$

---

My attempt: 
$$
\text{Hom}(U(1), S^1)=\mathbb{Z}.
$$
$$
\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_n, S^1)=\mathbb{Z}_n
$$
$$
\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, S^1)=?
$$

The following structure also may be helpful:
Wite $G_{con}$ for the connected component of the identity.
Write $G_{sol}$ for the largest connected normal solvable subgroup.
$G_{nil}$ for the largest connected normal nilpotent subgroup,
 we have a sequence of normal subgroups
$
1 \subseteq G_{nil} \subseteq G_{sol} \subseteq G_{con} \subseteq G.
$

---

> Can you determine the unfilled question marks above?

Comment: $\text{Hom}(\mathbb Z,S^1)=S^1$. In fact, $\text{Hom}(\mathbb Z,G)=G$ for any group $G$.

Comment: thanks +1 Lee Mosher.

Comment: I don't have a good answer in general, but when $G$ has finite fundamental group, $Hom(G,S^1) =\{e\}$.  For, in this case, let $G'$ denote any simple factor of the universal cover of $G$.  Now, if $f:G\rightarrow S^1$, then $\ker f$ has dimension $\dim G$ (if $f$ is trivial) or $\dim G - 1$ (if $f$ is not trivial.)  We get a map $G'\rightarrow G\rightarrow S^1$.  The kernel of this map is either all of $G'$, or is finite (because $G'$ is simple.)  If finite, $\ker f$ has dimension at most $\dim G - \dim G'$, so $\dim G' = 1$.  But there are no simple groups of dimension 1.

Comment: Thus, the kernel of the map $G'\rightarrow G\rightarrow S^1$ is all of $G'$.  Doing this for every simple factor in the universal cover of $G$ shows $f$ is trivial.  In particular, this answers the question about $Hom(G,\mathbb{Z})$ for any $G$ you list after "for example" and before the "my attempt".